# Displaying images in Django via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am trying to create a page with a list of names. Each name has there own modal(Note: this is in a `for` loop, so for each name, create a modal) which contains the Name, Description, and an image. The name and title appear, but not the image.

```
<!-- Toggle Button -->
{% for name in User_list %}
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ name }}" data-description="{{ name.description }}" data-image="{{ name.image }}" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog " href="#addBookDialog">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal hide fade" id="addBookDialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 id="nameId" /></h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="nameDescription" /></p>
        <div id='images'></div>


    </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
 var myNameId = $(this).data('id');
 var myNameDescription = $(this).data('description');
 var thumb = $(this).data('image');
 $(".modal-header #nameId").html( myNameId );
 $(".modal-body #nameDescription").html( myNameDescription );
 $(".modal-body #images").html("<img>" ,{src: thumb});
 //.html( myNameImage )
 // As pointed out in comments, 
 // it is superfluous to have to manually call the modal.
 });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct it(Note: I am using Twitter-Bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html()` method doesn't accept two parameters. You are attempting to create an element and initialize some of its properties. Try creating it properly and appending it:

```
$("#images").empty().append($("<img>", {src: thumb}));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tGbG6/

The `<div id='images'></div>` element's `id` should be unique, so you can use the selector `$("#images")` (this is true for the other selectors you have)...otherwise jQuery does some extra unnecessary work.

References:

- `html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html/
- `append()`: http://api.jquery.com/append/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

Comment: My apologies my friend, I did mean to do this, although, it still won't display an image. In the source code, it doesn't even read it as an `<img>` tag

Comment: @user2564732 My fault! I don't know what I was thinking - `html()` accepts a string, not a jQuery object. I just updated my answer; that should work.

Comment: thank you for your update! It now regonizes the code and gives me the source to the image. Is there a way to actually display it, for it won't appear? Please note that each modal is created in a for loop

Comment: @user2564732 I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean "gives me the source to the image"? You mean it displays that instead of the image itself? I think that means the path isn't correct and the image can't be found. Inspect the DOM and make sure the `<img>` is where it should be and make sure the `src` is correct

Comment: @user2564732 About your modals being in a for loop - well then you have duplicate `id`s on the page and that isn't good. Why are you generating multiple modals anyways? You should be able to reuse one modal

Comment: No, I mean in certain browsers, im using firefox, has an "Inspect Element" button, that allows me to view the source. It finds the image and the path is correct, it just won't appear.

Comment: Each ID is the the same, yes, but if you notice `{{ name }}` each ID is the specific name of the users in the Django DataBase. Same goes with description and image.

Comment: @user2564732 The `data-*` attributes don't matter when it comes to uniqueness, it's the `id` attributes I'm talking about in the modal. They need to be unique. But there really only needs to be one modal anyways. Here's how I'd set it up (as an example): http://jsfiddle.net/tGbG6/ . There's multiple `<li>`, but one modal, that they each target and populate

Comment: I don't know if this changes anything, but I do have a way of organizing these names. I don't know how yours works but mine doesn't. I need to import the id's, images, etc. from the database. They were all added via the Django admin site. What you have is raw html and javascript, I need the information to be pulled from the database. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for the jsfiddle example. That helped out.

Comment: @user2564732 Oh I completely understand that, but I'm trying to imitate that (because I obviously can't use a database in a jsFiddle) by using raw HTML. The HTML should end up being the same, so that's why I'm not sure why my code wouldn't work for you

Comment: @oh i figured it out. With the jsfiddle you provided, I tinkered around and found out I had to place `/media/` in front of the code pulling the data from the database. Thanks for your help!